# Picking object based on its TypeCode property

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, data-binding

I have been working on Survey program in C# (Silverlight) with Entity Framework
Data is kept in one table called question definition where I save all question definitions.

I question is different type based on *TypeCode* - it is string a char `"T"` - for text, `"O"` for options etc.

Anyway, how would you structure your design in a way that its easy to get a *question specific class*. In my case I have a form where person can click add new question and then they fill out question name, text followed by `type of the question` in tab view. So person can click on specific tab. I'm sort of lost now how to manage that. I can cast my base question to eg. `LabelQuestion`. Also when person does management of the question they would need to click on question and then I need to write something that would automatically cast that question to specific *type*. As far as I can tell from my limited knowledge of C# & Entity Framework I could do following.

- Extend `QuestionDefinition` table object which is made by entity framework in my base question. So that I don't have to encapsulate Question property inside it. That would be very easy to bind to and manage. However I'm not sure about entity framework and how it would manage that since it wouldn't be `QuestionDefinition` any more.
- Do what I have done and bind directly to `Question` property inside the class and use it as a wrapper. All properties that are contained in those *type specific* classes would be setters only and would write to `Question` property.

**Am I missing some other solutions? Which solutions is better and more reusable. How would you do it?**

[image: Class Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the second approach "Do what I have done and bind directly to Question property inside the class and use it as a wrapper. All properties that are contained in those type specific classes would be setters only and would write to Question property.". Also casting won't be an issue since you already have the information about the type of question.